# UltraGrid's EnterEditMode clears Selected Cells

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, grid, infragistics

here's my question.

I have an Infragistics `UltraGrid` with several columns. I want to have the next scenario: let's say I have 4 rows, then I move mouse over row 0 column 3, click and move mouse with clicked left mouse button to the bottom of the grid. In this case I have 4 selected cells ([0, 3], [1,3], [2,3], [3,3]) so `grid.Selected.Cells.Count = 4`. OK, now I want to **enter some number**. For that purpose in `KeyPress` event I have the line:

```
grid.PerformAction(UltraGridAction.EnterEditMode)
```

**Expectation result**: `grid.Selected.Cells.Count = 3.` (as far as one of the selected cells now in edit mode)
**Actual result**: End after this line I have `grid.Selected.Cells.Count = 0.`

So I'm wondering is this a native behavior and if so can I somehow change this situation?

Comment: I think that this is a normal behavior of any grid control. When you click on any cell you loose the current selection.

Comment: Yeah, I think so. One thing that makes me inconvenient is that vb6 control has different behavior: it remembers selected cells. So as a result I thought that I can simulate this situation in .net world

Comment: I checked this behavior in winforms datagridview, i am getting the expected behavior. Try using grid.PerformAction(UltraGridAction.EnterEditMode, false,true)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've tried your propose but still no success... Also have tried (UltraGridAction.EnterEditMode, true, false) even if it doesn't make sense in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've received the answer from Infragistics support and no, this is impossible to make my scenario: 
http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/86476/431344.aspx#431344

Thank you all for replies!